# Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I got this error message :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

When doing this script.

```
declare
    @startdt datetime,
    @enddt datetime

SET @startdt = '2014-04-04' +'00:00:01'
SET @EndDt ='2014-04-04' + ' 23:59:59'

EXEC sp_Insert_JC_Payment @startdt,@enddt
```

What should I do?

Where to put the convert script?

Thanks so much

Comment: My first thought is that your `set` statements will assign a string like this: `2014-040400:00:01`. You might need to add a delimiting space in there.

Comment: agreed with what mike said, same view here

Comment: You just need a space in front of the first zero in '00:00:01' ... otherwise, you're trying to convert '2014-04-0400:00:01' to a dt.

Answer (score 0):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible.

So in your case here, I would try to use:

```
SET @StartDate = '2014-04-04T00:00:01'
SET @EndDate   = '2014-04-04T23:59:59'
```

and then you should be go to go!

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
cast(d.Datetime as date) between @datefrom and @dateto
```